# Complex integrals over an ellipse instead of circle?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I was looking through past papers and found this integral:

[image]

Which should be evaluated over an ellipse with [image]

I've done these plenty of times over a circle with |z| = 2 etc, but where do I start in this case? Very lost, thanks for any help

Comment: Easy high-tech way: invoke Cauchy's integral theorem. Long low-tech way: first parametrize the circle, then scale it to parametrize the ellipse, then use that to write the appropriate expression for $z$ in terms of a parameter $t\in[0,2\pi)$, then integrate $\frac{z'(t)dt}{z(t)^2+1}$ over $[0,2\pi)$. Clever low-tech way: show $\oint_\gamma f(z)dz=0$ for any function $f$ and contour $\gamma$ which are invariant under $z\mapsto-z$, via an argument similar to the one in real variable calculus used to show $\int_{-a}^af(x)dx=0$ for odd functions $f$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
The ellipse equation is
$$
x^{2} + {y^{2} \over \pars{1/2}^{2}} = 1 
$$
The semi-axis along $y$ rest along $-1/2 < y < 1/2$ such that poles $\pm\ic$ of
$1/\pars{z^{2} + 1}$ are 'outside' the integration contour. Then,   $\tt\large\mbox{the integral vanishes out}$.